How do I add a custom template to a self-hosted Overleaf (fka ShareLatex) instance
I've started a local instance of overleaf/sharelatex and I'm trying to add a template class to the data directory so I can use it to compile a paper I'm working on, but I can't find the place to unzip the cls files into.
Based on the OVERLEAF_DATA_PATH variable in overleaf.rc, I put the template files into data/overleaf under the subdirectory data/template_files but it still can't compile the PDF.

I'm not sure if there is a cleaner option, but I made sure to upgrade the tex distribution to a full one:
docker exec sharelatex tlmgr install scheme-full
docker exec sharelatex tlmgr path add

However, the above command only works when the tex distribution (2023 in this case) matches the one in the repo tlmgr is looking in (2024). This meant that I had to find and run update-tlmgr-latest.sh first, from this documentation page.
Remember that docker changes are ephemeral and you'll need to commit the updated image:
docker commit sharelatex sharelatex:updated-full

and you may also need to update overleaf.rc to use the new image:
OVERLEAF_IMAGE_NAME=sharelatex/sharelatex:updated-full

Then rebuild the images using /opt/overleaf/bin/up after deleting the old ones.
